# How to add a textview into AppCompatPreferenceActivity

Tags: android, textview

I have added android's pre made settings activity to my app ( I took out some of the buttons and settings I didn't need in my app). I have tried manually adding a textview to `pref_general.xml` but my app crashes.  any idea why? Do I need to state it in the actual java code as well? I've just manually added a textview to the xml code.

pref_general.xml

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="example_switch"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations" />

  <!--  &lt;!&ndash; NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. &ndash;&gt;
    &lt;!&ndash; NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. &ndash;&gt;-->
    <EditTextPreference
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:key="example_text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name" />

    <!-- NOTE: Hide buttons to simplify the UI. Users can touch outside the dialog to
         dismiss it. -->
    <!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="-1"
        android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
        android:key="example_list"
        android:negativeButtonText="@null"
        android:positiveButtonText="@null"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textinfo"
        android:text="@string/textinfos"
        android:textColor="@color/colorText"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

settings.java

```
public class settings extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    /**
     * A preference value change listener that updates the preference's summary
     * to reflect its new value.
     */
    private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
            String stringValue = value.toString();

            if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
                // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
                // the preference's 'entries' list.
                ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
                int index = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);

                // Set the summary to reflect the new value.
                preference.setSummary(
                        index >= 0
                                ? listPreference.getEntries()[index]
                                : null);

            } else if (preference instanceof RingtonePreference) {
                // For ringtone preferences, look up the correct display value
                // using RingtoneManager.
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(stringValue)) {
                    // Empty values correspond to 'silent' (no ringtone).
                    preference.setSummary(R.string.pref_ringtone_silent);

                } else {
                    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                            preference.getContext(), Uri.parse(stringValue));

                    if (ringtone == null) {
                        // Clear the summary if there was a lookup error.
                        preference.setSummary(null);
                    } else {
                        // Set the summary to reflect the new ringtone display
                        // name.
                        String name = ringtone.getTitle(preference.getContext());
                        preference.setSummary(name);
                    }
                }

            } else {
                // For all other preferences, set the summary to the value's
                // simple string representation.
                preference.setSummary(stringValue);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * Helper method to determine if the device has an extra-large screen. For
     * example, 10" tablets are extra-large.
     */
    private static boolean isXLargeTablet(Context context) {
        return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE;
    }

    /**
     * Binds a preference's summary to its value. More specifically, when the
     * preference's value is changed, its summary (line of text below the
     * preference title) is updated to reflect the value. The summary is also
     * immediately updated upon calling this method. The exact display format is
     * dependent on the type of preference.
     *
     * @see #sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener
     */
    private static void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener);

        // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
        // current value.
        sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener.onPreferenceChange(preference,
                PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                        .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    private void setupActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
        return isXLargeTablet(this);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.pref_headers, target);
    }

    /**
     * This method stops fragment injection in malicious applications.
     * Make sure to deny any unknown fragments here.
     */
    protected boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return PreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || GeneralPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || DataSyncPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName)
                || NotificationPreferenceFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows general preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class GeneralPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_text"));
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("example_list"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), settings.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows notification preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class NotificationPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("notifications_new_message_ringtone"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), settings.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This fragment shows data and sync preferences only. It is used when the
     * activity is showing a two-pane settings UI.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public static class DataSyncPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_data_sync);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            // Bind the summaries of EditText/List/Dialog/Ringtone preferences
            // to their values. When their values change, their summaries are
            // updated to reflect the new value, per the Android Design
            // guidelines.
            bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference("sync_frequency"));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), settings.class));
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't actually if you really want textView in your prefScreen then use custom layout:

```
<Preference
    android:title="@string/label_pref_version"
    android:key="@string/pref_version"
    android:layout="@layout/pref" />
```

and define your layout here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/title"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:maxLines="2" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/go"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Preference should place its actual preference widget here. -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Better to add the main layout inside <ScrollView> if you have more Childs.